# Working with restricted string field values in .NET Core WebAPI 3.1

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, enums

I'm working on a **webapi** project using **.netcore**.

I have a model with the following properties:

```
public class Criterial {
  [Required]
  public string Field { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public Operator Operator { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Value { get; set; }

  public bool Result { get; set; }
}

public enum Operator {
    greater_than,
    equal_to,
    lower_than
}
```

I'm trying to use **enum** to restrict the values that the **Operator** propertie can receive, but when I make a POST request to the API I got the following scenario:

*POST Request Body:*

```
"criterials": [
    {
        "field": "amount",
        "operator": "greater_than",
        "value": "50"
    }
]
```

*Response from the API:*

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|7e53377-444fa4a723ac655c.",
    "errors": {
        "$.criterials[0].operator": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to LeagueOfFateApi.Models.Operator. Path: $.criterials[0].operator | LineNumber: 5 | BytePositionInLine: 26."
        ]
    }
}
```

Searching about the issue on the internet I found the **[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]** Data Annotation.

So I added it to my code and the issue was "solved":

```
[Required]
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public Operator Operator { get; set; }
```

*New response from the API:*

```
"criterials": [
    {
        "field": "amount",
        "operator": "greater_than",
        "value": "50",
        "result": false
    }
]
```

The problem is: in my **MongoDB** collection a new document was saved with the **int value 0** of the enums, and not the **string value "greater_than"**:

```
"Criterials" : [
    {
        "Field" : "amount",
        "Operator" : 0,
        "Value" : "50",
        "Result" : false
    }
]
```

Besides, another problem is that the "criterial" field can receive any int value with no restrictions.

Is there any other practical way to restrict a string's options without using enums? Or is there anything I can add to this solution using enums?

Thank you very much for your attention and your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could write custom set and get method for the Operator property.

You could set the Operator's type is string and use `Enum.IsDefined` to check the `Operator` value is  `enum Operator` or not.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
public class Criterial
{
    [Required]
    public string Field { get; set; }

    private string _Operator;

    [Required]
    public string Operator {
        get {
            return this._Operator;
        }
        set {
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Operator), value))
            {
                this._Operator = value;
            }
            else
            {
                this._Operator = "Error you used wrong string";
            }
        } 
    
    }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public bool Result { get; set; }
}

public enum Operator
{
    greater_than,
    equal_to,
    lower_than
}
```

Result:

[image]